# How to make new plugin setting checkbox default as checked

Tags: settings-api, customization

I have created a new plugin setting in an existing plugin that needs to be checked by default when users update to the new version because a lot of the original features are now activated by this checkbox.

This is the setting from my settings page:

```
<td>
    <?php printf(
        '<input id="bodhi_svgs_settings[advanced_mode]" name="bodhi_svgs_settings[advanced_mode]" type="checkbox" %2$s />', 'bodhi_svgs_settings_advanced_mode', checked( isset( $bodhi_svgs_options['advanced_mode'] ), true, false ) ); ?>
    <?php _e( 'Yes', 'svg-support' ); ?><br /><small class="description"><?php _e(' You don\'t need to enable this to simply use SVG files as images. Enabling this will trigger advanced options and SVG functionality such as inline rendering.', 'svg-support' ); ?></small>
</td>
```

I've looked at a number of solutions and can't seem to get it to work properly. I tried `checked( isset( $bodhi_svgs_options['advanced_mode'] ), true )` but that outputs checked="checked" to the page. I can't figure out how to do it without rewriting the entire options to work a different way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the checkbox and save the plugin options it will add option to the {prefix}_options table in the database. To make a checkbox checked you need to `update_option('option_id', 'value' )` for that checkbox on plugin activation. to do that you need to register plugin activation hook. Place the below code in the main plugin file.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'am_plugin_activate' );
function am_plugin_activate() {
    // plugin activation code here...
    update_option('checkbox_id', true );
}
```

this will make the checkbox checked. to make the checkbox checked on plugin update you need to hook a function on `upgrader_process_complete` action hook. e.g;

```
add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', 'am_plugin_upgrate',10, 2);
function am_plugin_upgrate( $upgrader_object, $options ) {
    // plugin update code here....
}
```

for reference please take a look at [upgrader_process_complete](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/upgrader_process_complete), [Discussion Plugin Activation Hooks](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2010/10/27/plugin-activation-hooks/) and [Plugin activation hook discussion](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2010/10/27/plugin-activation-hooks-no-longer-fire-for-updates/)

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I'm not sure what to set as `'checkbox_id'`. I tried `'bodhi_svgs_settings[advanced_mode]'`, `'advanced_mode'`, `$bodhi_svgs_options['advanced_mode']`. I also tried putting `global $bodhi_svgs_options;` inside the function. I'm sure I'm missing something simple! Your solution looks awesome though, thank you.

Comment: `checkbox_id` is the option name you wish to update. assuming your checkbox has it's own id when you registered your setting page, that's what goes there. If you save all your options as an array, then you need to modify the array at the index which contains your option value. then use `update_option()`

Comment: that's where I'm confused, I thought my option name was `advanced_mode`...

Comment: rereading your question. your option name in `wp_options` table seem to be `bodhi_svgs_settings` and your checkbox id seems to be `advanced_mode`.  Then you would use `update_options( 'bodhi_svgs_settings',  array( 'advanced_mode' => true ) );`

Comment: awesome, that worked with the slight change to `update_option` rather than `update_options`. But now all of the other existing settings are cleared.

Comment: I'm now trying to get the current options and modify only the `'advanced_mode'` one.

Comment: great. now get previous options and save in 1st array(), save new option in 2nd array(), merge both arrays and update the options.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, got this one sorted. Now to only fire it once and then somehow remove the code so it won't run again in the future. Cheers!